# convert unix output to integer for use as Applescript variable

Tags: unix, applescript

I'm using the **do shell script** command in AppleScript to count the number of files that match a certain criteria.  However, instead of returning an integer, my expression returns a string with a series of leading spaces.  What I've written below *works*, but I'm not wild about using the spaces in the **if** condition (yeah -- just being a bit OCD :-).  How might I convert the result to an integer?

```
set fileCount to do shell script "ls -l ~/Downloads/UserExport_*.csv.txt | wc -l"
if (fileCount = "       2") then
```

Comment: As a crude workaround, `ls | grep -c .` will not be space-padded. (You also don't need the `-l` flag for `ls`, anyway.)

Comment: Coerce it to integer like anything else - `fileCount as integer`

Answer (score 0):

Use `as integer`like this :

```
set fileCount to (do shell script "ls -l ~/Downloads/UserExport_*.csv.txt | wc -l") as integer
if fileCount = 2 then
```

Comment: Woah -- I could have sworn I tried that :-/  whoops!  Thank so much for the help!!! :-D